# How to add the selected ID values to a list after the form is submitted ?

Tags: coldfusion

Once the form is submitted  all the values are separated like this

GETL794BLACK  2779
GETL794NAVY   2657
GETL794SAHARA 2111

GETL794WHITE  2110

```
<div>Available Colors:</div>
            <cfoutput query="GetL794" group="color">
                    <div>
                    <select size="1" name="GetL794#color#">
                        <option value="0">#color_desc#</option><cfoutput><option value="#id#">#color_desc# - #size# - $#price#</option></cfoutput>
                    </select>
                    </div>
            </cfoutput>
```

How to add the selected ID values to a list after the form is submitted ?

In other words , to have the list equal =

```
<cfset coldfusion_list = "2779,2657,2111,2110">
```

Comment: Replace the selects on your form with checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1)
Give all your `<select>` the same name. coldfusion will automatically make a list out of it when the form submits.

Option 2)
Loop over the values and append them to a list:

```
    <cfset list = "">

    <cfloop query="GetL794" group="color">
       <cfif StructKeyExists(FORM, 'GetL794#color#') and len(FORM['GetL794' & color])>
          <cfset list = listAppend(list,FORM['GetL794' & color])>
       </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Option 1 is a good idea.  For option 2, that query won't necessarily exist.